# How to disable HttpHandlers for production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My website is using the MSCaptcha library for captcha functionality. The implementation requires handlers to be defined in the web.config file, a web/httphandler for older IIS and the development server, and a webServer/handler for IIS7+.

Now, every time I publish my project to the production server (which runs IIS7), I get an internal server error message because http handlers have been defined in the config file. Once removed, the website runs perfectly. However, when I am testing locally I need to have http handlers defined as the dev server doesn't seem to read webServer/handlers.

Obviously one solution is to simply remove the httphandlers temporarily every time I publish my website to the production server, but since I do this pretty often it is a bit cumbersome. Is there any way to specify when the http handlers should and should not be included in the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use configuration file transforms and build names to accomplish this. Create web.config that has the dev/local setup, then create a transform for release mode that removes your entry and creates the proper IIS7+ one.

Then whenever you deploy release mode it'll be right for your release environment!

This functionality is built into VS, but for non-web apps it won't work without using something like SlowCheetah.

Examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: I edited the URL so that it would not be specific to .NET 4.5.

Comment: I tried this by adding xtd:Transform="Insert" to the httpHandlers tag in Web.Debug.Config (having defined no httpHandlers tag in the core Web.Config file). The component is however still not working after building the debug version and running it.

Comment: Preview the transform and see what it does vs what you expect it to do.

Comment: Apparently the Transform attribute only works on IIS, because the web.config file was properly changed after publishing the website to the production server, but remained the same when running the site on a local dev server. Anyway, works now. Thanks!